# Notepad++ How would I add a new line between two specific lines using the replace tool

Tags: replace, notepad++

I am a novice modder and am trying to create a mod for a video game. There is a specific line I would like to add between every search instance. For example:

This is how its currently structured:

```
<property name="IsQuestGiver" value="false"/>
<effect_group name="Base Effects">
```

I would like to achieve this to all 200 instances in the file:

```
<property name="IsQuestGiver" value="false"/>
<property name="BodyHitPoints" value="9999"/>
<effect_group name="Base Effects">
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

I fiddled around with the replace tool but couldnt figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Search with regular expression search mode:

`<property name="IsQuestGiver" value="false"/>`

Replace text:

`$0\n<property name="BodyHitPoints" value="9999"/>\n`

Normally in regexp you need to escape some characters with `\` like `/`, but not in notepad++.

The $0 is the match value, so rather than replacing the match text you can simply use $0.

`\n` is a new line character. If your using windows you might need to use `\r\n` instead.

Comment: There're no needs to escape `"` and `/`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise this about notepad++, udated answer